# R: Strange error using grubbs.test when type = 20

Tags: r, error-handling, outliers

```
library(outliers)
data <- read.table('uscrime.txt', header = T)
grubbs.test(data$Crime, type = 10)
```

Everything works fine when type = 10 ([identify whether or not a dataset’s maximum value is an outlier](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/09/how-to-identify-outliers-grubbs-test-in-r-2/)). However, when I set type as 20 (identify two large values outlier or not), the output has an error:

> Error in qgrubbs(q, n, type, rev = TRUE) : n must be in range 3-30

The strange thing is I didn't even use the function **qgrubbs**. What's wrong?

*Data source: http://www.statsci.org/data/general/uscrime.txt*

Comment: You didn't call `qgrubbs` explicitly, but type in `grubbs.test` and look at its source code, namely it calls [`pval = 1-pgrubbs(g,n,type=11)`](https://github.com/cran/outliers/blob/master/R/grubbs.test.R#L11). Before that line, see that it defines `n` as [`n <- length(x)`](https://github.com/cran/outliers/blob/master/R/grubbs.test.R#L11), which in this case is the same as `nrow(data)`, 47 rows as I see it now. Apparently that test is not fit for more than 30 data?